# Python adding a new control gives error

Tags: javascript, python, urllib2, mechanize

I am using mechanize in Python .  I am unable to set the value of a SelectControl element.

The webpage I am trying to crawl is `http://www.mcxindia.com/SitePages/indexhistory.aspx` 
the part source code which I am concerned about is :

```
<tr>
                            <td bgcolor="#f5f4f5" class="txtblue"><table border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                <tr>
                                  <td><table id="mRbtLstSpotFut" border="0" style="font-weight:normal;height:85px;width:208px;">
                <tr>
                    <td><input id="mRbtLstSpotFut_0" type="radio" name="mRbtLstSpotFut" value="1" checked="checked" /><label for="mRbtLstSpotFut_0">Commodity Future Indexes</label></td>
                </tr><tr>
                    <td><input id="mRbtLstSpotFut_1" type="radio" name="mRbtLstSpotFut" value="0" onclick="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'mRbtLstSpotFut$1\',\'\')', 0)" /><label for="mRbtLstSpotFut_1">Commodity Spot Indexes</label></td>
                </tr><tr>
                    <td><input id="mRbtLstSpotFut_2" type="radio" name="mRbtLstSpotFut" value="2" onclick="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'mRbtLstSpotFut$2\',\'\')', 0)" /><label for="mRbtLstSpotFut_2">Rainfall Indexes</label></td>
                </tr>
            </table></td>
                                  <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                  <td rowspan="3" valign="top"><p style="margin-top: 3px; margin-bottom: 0; margin-left: 0" align="justify">

                                    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3">
                                      <tr>
                                        <td class="tablerowtxt1"> Selected Index</td>
                                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                        <td colspan="2"><select name="mDdlOtherIndex" id="mDdlOtherIndex" class="dd" style="width:170px;">
                <option selected="selected" value="323">MCXCOMDEX</option>
                <option value="324">MCXMETAL</option>
                <option value="325">MCXENERGY</option>
                <option value="326">MCXAGRI</option>

            </select></td>
```

Now I can change the value of the 2nd radio button which I am doing by

```
br.select_form(nr=0)
br.set_all_readonly(False)
br.form['mTbFromDate']='08/01/2013'
br.form['mTbToDate']='08/08/2013'
br.form.set_value(['0'],name='mRbtLstSpotFut')
```

But I also want to select the option value '327' which is not present(since it comes up by JS when the radio button is clicked, which mechanize cannot handle)

So I am trying to add a new control to the form like

```
<option value="327">MCXENERGY</option>
```

I am trying this, but this does not work.

```
br.form.new_control('text','option',{'value':'327'})
br.form.fixup()
br.form['mDdlOtherIndex']= ['327']
```

But this gives me the following error:

```
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\mechanize\_form.py", line 2006
mechanize._form.ItemNotFoundError: insufficient items with name '327'
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to create `select` and then option. If you don't have select then it just can't choose it.

Example of select (option is inside of the select):

```
<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Comment: But that would create another select control.

Comment: Select is already there in the source...please look carefully !

Comment: It is in the source of what you received with JavaScript. Are you also getting it in mechanize (without JavaScript)?

Comment: yes, it is able to find the select control, but i need to add another element to it. Please help me out